# Is this word order acceptable or wrong?

Tags: word-order

Do you think that these sentences sound awful or they can be used in principle?

1 The cars of what color do you like?

2 People of what professions work in school?

3 The child of which one of you is this?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to phrase the questions this way?

Comment: For those who want to close the question I should point out that "word order" is a very important aspect in English. As you are natives, you take for granted your ability to discern between natural and unnatural word orders. Instead of suggesting closing it, you had better explain the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if they are wrong, but I certainly have not heard them before.

For number 3, if you are asking the question directly to a group of people in front of you, you could always ask this way:

> 3. Whose child is this?

For number 1, you could ask the following:

> 1. What color would you like your car to be? >What is your preferred color for cars? What color car do you like?

Comment: Do you speak American or British English?